# Continuous-time Switched Linear Systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, spectral-radius

Suppose we have a set of matrices $\Sigma$ and a switching rule $\sigma: \mathbb{R} \to \Sigma$. It is known in the discrete case that if the [joint spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_spectral_radius), $\rho(\Sigma)$, is less than one, then the following so called discrete-time switched linear dynamical system is convergent

$$
x_{t + 1} = \sigma(t)x_t.
$$

What is known about the continuous case? Does there exist a condition on the joint spectral radius of $\Sigma$ that would imply that the following dynamical system is globally asymptotically stable?

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = (\sigma(t)-I)x
$$

Comment: Presumably you would rather that the real parts of the spectra of $\Sigma$ are negative? It is trivial to create an unstable example satisfying the condition above with a single matrix. Also, I imagine that even in the discrete case that you need some uniformity.

Comment: Whoops, I put down the wrong inequality, thanks so much for the comment. More generally, I'm interested in the existence of a condition on the joint spectral radius that would imply asymptotic stability. As far as I'm aware, $\rho(\Sigma) < 1$ is equivalent to convergence in the discrete case when $\Sigma$ is finite or compact.

Comment: Does the switchings occur at discrete times? If yes you can use the same condition with matrices $e^{\Sigma h_t}$ where $h_t$ is the switching interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For continuous-time linear switched systems, there exists an equivalent notion of the JSR, it is the "least measure value" of the set of matrices. It is proven that the system is exp. stable iff this quantity is negative. For a formal definition and properties of this notion, refer to section 2.3.3 in the book of Sun&Ge : Stability Theory of Switched Dynamical Systems(2011). In general, the condition $\rho(\Sigma)<1$ does not tell about the stability in the continuous-time case. For more results on the stability equivalence between the continuous-time and discrete-time cases, refer to section 3.5 in Jacques Theys thesis: Joint Spectral Radius: theory and approximations (2009).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the question correctly, the answer is no.

Let $\sigma(t) = \begin{bmatrix}0 & e^t \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. That is, $\Sigma = \{ \sigma(t) | t \in \mathbb{R}\}$, and $\rho(\Sigma) = 0$

However, the system $\dot{x}=(\sigma(t)-I) x$ is not asymptotically stable, starting from $x(0)=(0,v)$, we have $x(t) = (v, e^{-t}v)$.